# Values between Forms c#

Tags: c#, forms

I need to read some values on my second form from the first one and I need to modify these values, so they can't be constants (they are strings and ints).
How can I do this?

Comment: Hello, please post the code that you have and/or code that you have tried to give all of us a better idea on how to help you!

Comment: Insert the title of your question in the search field and you will find thousands of answers on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably the "first form" has some reference to the "second form"?  Something like this:

```
// somewhere in the "first form"
var secondForm = new SecondForm();
secondForm.Show();
```

In that case your `SecondForm` class can expose those values as properties.  Something like:

```
public class SecondForm : Form
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }

    // etc.
```

Internally, `SecondForm` would use that property like any instance variable.  Externally, other code can reference that property:

```
// somewhere in the "first form"
var something = secondForm.SomeProperty;
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also try to use `Server.Transfer()`

so in your first form:

```
protected void btnSendToForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
        Server.Transfer("formB.aspx",true );
}
```

with the button being an ASP control on your first form
This will automatically submit/transfer all your form variables

Answer (score 0):

do like that for first form

```
  namespace WindowsFormsApplication9
    {
        public partial class frm_main : Form
        {
            frm_main fm = new frm_main();
            public frm_main()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                fm = this;
            }
            string name1, name2;
```

then in second form:
for example that variable name i call it from another form :
`frm_main.fm.name`="any value"